# The meaning of two seemingly undefined control-sequences in the PGF source code

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, sourcecode

The following macro is defined in `<pgf/tikz installation dir>/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex`.

```
% Usage:
% \pgfutil@in@{one}{three two one}
% \ifpgfutil@in@
%   -> will be true!
% \else
% \fi
%
% \pgfutil@in@{,}{1234,456567}
% \ifpgfutil@in@
%   -> will be true!
% \else
% \fi
\def\pgfutil@in@#1#2{%
 \def\pgfutil@in@@##1#1##2##3\pgfutil@in@@{%
  \ifx\pgfutil@in@##2\pgfutil@in@false\else\pgfutil@in@true\fi}%
 \pgfutil@in@@#2#1\pgfutil@in@\pgfutil@in@@}
```

The code uses the control-sequences `\pgfutil@in@false` and `\pgfutil@in@true`. However, these are the only occurrences of these control-sequences not only in this file, but in the entire pgf/tikz source code. In particular, these control sequences are nowhere `\def`ined or `\let` to.

So what is their purpose? To cause an unavoidable error? It seems like a contorted way to do this.

I thought maybe I was parsing them wrong, and actually `false` and `true` are arguments that are passed to `\pgfutil@in@`, i.e. `\pgfutil@in@false` should be construed as `\pgfutil@in@ false`. But this is not how TeX would interpret it, is it? TeX would "swallow" everything from `\` till the next non-category-11 token, so it would consider the control-sequence's name to be `pgfutil@in@false`.

Comment: Have you ever considered looking for `\ifpgfutil@in@`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the way TeX handles ifs.  Further up you'll find

```
\newif\ifpgfutil@in@
```

The statements

```
\pgfutil@in@true
\pgfutil@in@false
```

have the effect to redefine `\ifpgfutil@in@` to `\iftrue` and `\iffalse`, respectively.

The following Plain TeX example (LaTeX similarly)

```
\catcode`@=11 % makeatletter
\newif\ifpgfutil@in@
\show\pgfutil@in@true
\show\pgfutil@in@false
\bye
```

will display this in the log

```
> \pgfutil@in@true=macro:
->\let \ifpgfutil@in@ \iftrue .
l.4 \show\pgfutil@in@true

> \pgfutil@in@false=macro:
->\let \ifpgfutil@in@ \iffalse .
l.5 \show\pgfutil@in@false
```

This is described in [The TeXbook](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) in »Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros)«

> To facilitate `\if...` constructions, plain TeX has a
>   `\newif` macro, such that after you say `\newif\ifabc` three
>   control sequences will be defined: `\ifabc` (for testing the switch),
>   `\abctrue` (for making the switch true), and `\abcfalse` (for making
>   it false). The `\phantom` problem is now solved in Appendix B by writing
>
> ```
> \newif\ifhph \newif\ifvph
> \def\hphantom{\hphtrue\vphfalse\phant}
> \endtt
> ```
>
> and with similar definitions of `\vphantom` and `\phantom`. There is no
>   longer any need for a `\ph` macro; again `\phant` tests `\ifhph` and
>   `\ifvph`. Appendix E contains other examples of conditionals created
>   by `\newif`. New conditionals are initially false.